# How to show: $\exists$ a subspace $L$ of a Hilbert space $H$ such that $H\neq L\oplus L^{\perp}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

How to show: $\exists$ a subspace $L$ of a Hilbert space $H$ such that $H\neq L\oplus L^{\perp}$.

Let consider $H=l_2$ where $l_2=\lbrace x=(x_n)^\infty_1: \sum^\infty_1 |x_n|^2<\infty \rbrace $

and if we choose $L$ s.t. $L=\mathrm{span}(e_{2k})^\infty_{k=1}$, then we cannot conclude that $H\neq L\oplus L^{\perp}$.

Are we on right track?
Could you please help?

Comment: What happens if $L$ is a proper dense subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $L$ suggested in the OP or any closed subspace won't work: we can use orthogonal projection in order to show that $L\oplus L^\perp=H$.

However, if $L$ is not closed, the equality $L\oplus L^\perp=H$ may not hold. For example, consider $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ and $$L:=\operatorname{span}(e_k,k\geqslant 0).$$ 
Then $L^\perp=\{(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z),x_k=0 \mbox{ for each }k\geqslant 0\}$, hence $L\oplus L^\perp=\{(x_k)\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z), \mbox{ for some }n, 
x_k=0 \mbox{ whenever }k\geqslant n\}$.

Alternatively, as kahen suggest, each dense subspace $V$ of $H$ may be written as $L\oplus L^{\perp}$. for some $L$ (actually take $L=V$).

Comment: But then for the L that you have given satisfies: $L\oplus L^\perp = H$. isn't it so since $L=\bar{L}$?

Comment: No, the $L$ I gave is not closed (for example the sequence given by $\sum_{k\geqslant 0}2^{-k}e_k$ is in the closure of $L$ but not in $L$.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand: can't we chose $c_k=2^{-k}$ and $x=\sum c_k e_k$ which means $x\in L$

Comment: The span consists of _finite_ linear combination of elements of the form $e_k$.

Comment: Ah right, thanks

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Actually, if $L$ is not closed, then the equality $L\oplus L^\perp=H$ *does not* hold (it doesn't just *may not* hold). Indeed, an element $x\in\overline{L}\setminus L$ cannot be written as $x=l+p$, with $l\in L$ and $p\in L^\perp$.